# Creating a list of unique senders from Thunderbird mail files through the command-line

Tags: command-line, email, thunderbird

I've got some large mailboxes and using Thunderbird, that means that I have several `mbox` files. These single files contain all e-mails in a particular folder. Now, I would like to get some data on the senders in a particular folder. My ideal statistic would be to get all unique senders, and the number of times their e-mail is in that folder. Ej:

- John A: 10x
- Maria B: 5x

etc.

I've tried some `grep` options but I also get X-headers if I grep only 'From:', and I'm not sure how to exclude these other headers. Anybody any idea if this can be done from the command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, we need to reliably get the `From` header, which can be done with a restrictive grep regular expression.

```
% grep --no-filename --ignore-case '^From:' test.eml
From: mgorven@example.com
```

Next we need to count the number of occurrences, which can be done with [`uniq -c`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/uniq.1posix.html) (which requires a sorted list).

```
% grep --no-filename --ignore-case '^From:' *.eml | sort | uniq --count
      1 From: mgorven@example.com
      3 From: mgorven@example.net
```

We can then sort the output by occurrence, to get the most frequent at the top.

```
% grep --no-filename --ignore-case '^From:' *.eml | sort | uniq --count | sort --general-numeric-sort --reverse
      3 From: mgorven@example.net
      1 From: mgorven@example.com
```

Comment: Absolutely awesome!!! Worked like a charm, thanks!